# github: how to reference an issue in a commit from a different repository?

Tags: github

I have two repositories:

- Repository A
- Repository B

I also have a project:

- Project X

This Project X has Repository A and Repository B as linked repositories.

In Repository A I created several issues:

- Issue 1
- Issue 2
- Issue 3

All these issues are appearing on the kanban board of Project X.
When I now do a commit on Repository B:

```
closes #1
```

The commit wont get linked to the Issue 1 of Repository A.
Can I configure the project in a way that I can create such references from commits from different Repositories? Or do I use this wrong?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

`#1` refers to issue 1 in this repo.

`username/repoA#1` refers to issue 1 in username's repoA.

`org/repoA#1` refers to issue 1 in org's repoA.

You would use either of the last two options

See [Autolinked references and URLs: Issues and pull requests](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/writing-on-github/working-with-advanced-formatting/autolinked-references-and-urls).

Comment: how about multiple ones?

Comment: @Maadiah Reference them separately. repoA#1 repoA#2 repoA#3